# Include the record in same JSP returned from controller. If record is there then show the record as a table or give a message

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, controller

Include the record in the same JSP returned from the controller. If any record is there then show the record as a table or give a message

I have done it on two different JSP pages. I need to do it on a single page. I need to update the controller as I am only allowed to return the same jsp.[mappings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woHaP.png)

```
@Controller  
public class EmpController {  
    @Autowired  
    EmpDao dao;
   
    @PostMapping("/viewemp")  
    public String viewemp(@RequestParam(value="start") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") Date start,
            @RequestParam(value="end") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") Date end, Model m){  
        List<Event> list=dao.getEmployees(start,end);  
        if(list.size()==0) return "index";
        m.addAttribute("list",list);
        return "viewemp";
    }   
}
```

jsp1:

```
<center>
<h1> Search Event</h1>
   <form method="post" action="viewemp">  
   Start Date: <input type="date" id="start" name="start"/>
    End Date: <input type="date" id="end" name="end"/>
    <input type="submit" value="find" />
    </form></center>
```

jsp2:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>  

<h1>Event List</h1>
<table border="2" width="70%" cellpadding="2">
<tr><th>eventName</th><th>eventOrgName</th><th>eventFare</th><th>startDate</th><th>endDate</th></tr>
<c:forEach var="emp" items="${list}"> 
<tr>
<td>${emp.eventName}</td>
<td>${emp.eventOrgName}</td>
<td>${emp.eventFare}</td>
<td>${emp.startDate}</td>
<td>${emp.endDate}</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
<br/>
```

I need to add jsp2 inside jsp1 if it has any record. like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9XdM.png)